# Java components replacement JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, interface

I'm trying to create an application in 3 parts : 3 labels and 3 gridlayouts. When we click on a label, the corresponding gridlayout disappear and the frame replace automatically the components at the right place. I created a simple snippet :

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestLayout extends JFrame{
    private JPanel content;
    private JLabel[] lbl;
    private JPanel[] pnl;
    private Boolean[] ih;

    public TestLayout(){
        setTitle("Test");
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lbl = new JLabel[3];
        pnl = new JPanel[3];
        ih  = new Boolean[3];

        content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6, 1));
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            lbl[i] = new JLabel("Label" + i);
            lbl[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  
            {  
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  
                {  
                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                        if(e.getSource() == lbl[i]){
                            //pnl[i].setVisible(!pnl[i].isVisible());
                            if(ih[i]) content.remove(pnl[i]);
                            else content.add(pnl[i]);
                            ih[i] = !ih[i];
                        }
                    }

                }  
            }); 
            pnl[i] = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        }

        for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            pnl[0].add(new Button("" + (i+1)));
            pnl[1].add(new Button("" + (i+10)));
            pnl[2].add(new Button("" + (i+19)));
        }

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            content.add(lbl[i]);
            content.add(pnl[i]);
            ih[i] = true;
        }

        add(content);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestLayout();
    }   
}
```

The first problem is the use of a global gridlayout which resize all the components at the same size, but I think it would be better if labels could be smaller than the grilayouts.

The second problem is that even if the gridlayout is removed or setVisible(false), it still take a blank place in the global container.

What I get :

[image]

What I was expecting :

[image]

The only thing I don't wanna use is a GridBagLayout.

I was thinking about create a method init() which one remove all components of the global container then re add all the labels and all the panels, then create another method which do the exact same as the init() method but take a number as parameter (for example 2) then re add all the components excepting the second gridlayout. But I think it's a dirty way to do that because the container will content an empty case at the end and I think there is a better way than removing and re adding all the components (which basically doesn't solve the first problem of label's size)

How can I avoid theses problems ?

Comment: This question is far too broad

Comment: Basically I was expecting a tip to use another layout which could fit better to my problem instead of a GridLayout and avoiding the use of a GridBagLayout

Comment: Too hard to answer such a broad question. Hint: BoxLayout ?

Comment: Yes the boxlayout seems to be the solution of both of my problems. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a vertical `BoxLayout`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: It looks like it's exactly what I was looking for, thanks !